# WPF: bind Icon property to a System.Drawing.Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have bound my menu items to a menu item model class using following code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <classes:IconConverter x:Key="IconConverter"/>

    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="BoundMenuItemStyle">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Header}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Children}" />
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}" />
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Path=Icon, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BoundMenuItemStyle}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The `Icon` property of the model class is of type `System.Drawing.Icon`. So I wrote a converter to convert it to an `ImageSource`:

```
class IconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is System.Drawing.Icon)
        {
            var icon = value as System.Drawing.Icon;
            ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                icon.Handle,
                System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            return imageSource;
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The problem is instead of an icon, I get a string in my menus.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I should return an instance of `Image` control from my converter:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is System.Drawing.Icon)
        {
            var icon = value as System.Drawing.Icon;
            ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                icon.Handle,
                System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            img.Source = imageSource;
            return img;
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
```